# Wait for loading page after button click

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, invokemember

I want to be able to click on button and than wait for the page to load. 
I search, but there is no solution that work correctly.
This is part of code:

```
el = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LoginButton");
el.InvokeMember("click");
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

I need it to be that after click, the application will load the page, and only then go to another page. 
Also, `webBrowser1.Navigate(url)` must be in the same method as click. Because it all in a loop.

Please help.

**EDITED.**
**More code** (first code was and example of what i need)

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();

            bool flag = true;

            while (flag)
            {
                flag = false;

                foreach (HtmlElement he2 in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
                {
                    if (he2.GetAttribute("href").Contains("profile.php?ID="))
                    {
                        list1.Add(he2.InnerText);
                    }

                }

                foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
                {

                    if (he.InnerHtml == "Next")
                    {
                        flag = true;

                        he.InvokeMember("click");


                    }
                }


            }
```

When I click, next page must load, and i have to parse tag on next page, but it begin parse page before next page is load, so it parse the same page.

Comment: can you add your target url

Comment: @IRSOG, sorry, but no. I login to site, and then go to private message.

Comment: what do you want to do after el.InvokeMember("click"); happens ?

Comment: @IRSOG I go to next page, and parse starts, but I need to wait before next page load

Comment: did you tried webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted event?

Comment: @IRSOG yes, but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I just got href from my button and used this code(insted of he.InvokeMember("click"))
:

```
 webBrowser1.Navigate(url_next);
 while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     Application.DoEvents();
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DocumentCompleted` event to find out when the login has completed.

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
el = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("LoginButton");
el.InvokeMember("click");

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri myUrl = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
    if (e.Url == myUrl)
    {
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doen't help, because i have some code after click, how can i get back?

Comment: Why not just move the rest of the code into the event handler? Or seperate that code into a new method and call it from the event handler?

Comment: Surely once you have navigated to the page you do not need to continue looping that part? Post more code if you want anymore help.